# Change name of alert in jscript

Tags: javascript, html, dialog

Is there a way to change the name of a alert dialog box in jscript, like instead of it saying `("Alert" "Message")` can it say something like `("Hello" "Message")` this is the script im using:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('message');return false;">Click Here</a>
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Do you mean: `hello()` instead of `alert()`?

Comment: It is worth pointing out here that when you call alert in Firefox (5 and up I believe), there is no title on the dialog box! :-)

Comment: @JaredFarrish No I mean instead of the dialog box saying Alert: then whatever I said, I want the Alert: to be custom. But it looks like thats impossible.

Comment: @RayToal Thanks, I was using it in a WebKit browser (android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as far as I am aware with the default basic Javascript `alert()` dialog box.

In fact, different browsers will have different title bars on the dialog. Some have "Alert", others have "The page at http://someurl.com says:" and it goes on.

A far prettier, and more customisable option is to consider using something like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com). It has features like the [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message), which create a nicer, in-page dialog box with customisable buttons, title, and content.

It requires use of the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library, which is a hugely popular Javascript library to greatly ease Javascript development, and plainly, make it more *fun*.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to alias `alert` it would be:

```
var t = alert;
t('blah');
```

If you want to change the text of the alert box's title bar, you can not.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement an alert with a custom title, would be to implement a custom dialog.  You may want to look in to using [jQuery UI Dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  There are many other implementations of custom Dialog controls.  Such as [SimpleModal Dialog](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: no.

However, *alert* is a host method and browsers can chose to implement it however they like. But all browsers currently do not let script modify the standard alert dialogue. You can create your own alert dialogue though using a suitably styled and positioned element.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean function renaming

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hello(msg){
    alert(msg);
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="hello('message');return false;">Click Here</a>
```